# Generalisation of the density states of phonons

Tags: electrons, solid-state-physics, phonons, density-of-states

Is it possible to generalize de density of states for phonons $\left( \left(\frac{L}{2\pi} \right )^3  \int \frac{dS_\omega}{v_g}\right)$ to a density of states which is also applicable to Bloch electrons?

I thought about changing $v_g$ to $v_f$ (the Fermi velocity), but that did not agree with de density of states for electrons.

Comment: What exactly is $dS_\omega $ here? Are you assuming $v_g$ is a constant?

Comment: @BySymmetry : the element of volume between the constant frequency surfaces $\omega$ and $\omega + d\omega$ is the cylinder of base $dS_\omega$, $v_g$ is not constant

Answer (score 1):

The following equations for the density of states are applicable in all (3D) situations:*

$$g\left(E\right) = \int \frac{d\mathbf{k}}{4\pi^3} \delta\left(E-E\left(\mathbf{k}\right)\right) = \int_{S\left(E\right)} \frac{dS}{4\pi^3}\frac{1}{\left|\nabla E\left(\mathbf{k}\right)\right|}$$

See Ashcroft and Mermin equations 8.57 and 8.63 (and the surrounding section). You're basically quoting the right-most part of the equation; $\left|\nabla E\left(\mathbf{k}\right)\right|$ is proportional to the group velocity: $\mathbf{v}\left(E\right) = \frac{1}{\hbar} \nabla E\left(\mathbf{k}\right)$ (Ashcroft and Mermin equation 8.51), which follows from the fact that $E = \hbar \omega$.

However, the group velocity is not constant. The Fermi velocity is the group velocity only for certain $\mathbf{k}$ --- not for all $\mathbf{k}$. So, if you want to use the equation, you need to have the group velocity be a function of $\mathbf{k}$.

Note that for phonons, you can sometimes approximate the group velocity as being constant because its dispersion relation is roughly linear near $\mathbf{k} = 0$. Except in special situations (e.g. graphene), Bloch electrons have mass, so their dispersion relation will not be linear, and their group velocity will not be constant.

EDIT:

* Those equations are for electrons, and the most common convention for electrons is to include an extra factor of 2 because the electron states are (normally) two-fold degenerate. Sometimes this degeneracy factor is kept separate from the density of states because the degeneracy is not set in stone. E.g. you can get rid of it by applying a magnetic field.

Comment: Why is the group velocity equal to $\nabla E(k)$, I think it's $\nabla_k\omega$, are those 2 definitions equivalent?

Comment: $E=\hbar\omega$, so I should say proportional instead of equal.

Comment: I should add that, depending on how you defined the density of states ($g\left(\omega\right)d\omega$ vs $g\left(E\right)dE$), you'll gain or loose a factor of $\hbar$ (or equivalently change from $v_g$ to $\left|\nabla E\left(\mathbf{k}\right)\right|$). It's still the same equation at heart. Phonons and electrons don't get different treatment. It's simply a question of how many modes are in the range $\left[E, E+dE\right]$.

Comment: Thanks for that, when I have the dispersion relation for electrons? (I use this book : introduction to solid state physics - Kittel)  How should I integrate over dS, since nothing in that integral is directely dependend of S?

Comment: When talking about electrons, you generally use the term "band structure" instead of "dispersion relation". There are many methods for calculating or measuring the band structure of a material. In general, they can be quite complicated. What system are you dealing with? As for calculating the density of states from the band structure, see my answer to this post https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/303140/density-of-phonon-states-from-dispersion-relation/303415#303415

Answer (score 0):

I thought about this : 
Density of states =  $\left( \left(\frac{L}{2\pi} \right )^3  \int \frac{dS_\omega}{v_g}\right)$ with $v_g = \frac{d\epsilon}{dk}$, with $\epsilon = \hbar^2k^2/2m$ then is $v_g = \hbar^2k/2 = \hbar^2/m \sqrt{2\epsilon m /\hbar^2}$ and thus for the density of states (with $\int d_S = 4\pi k^2$ ) I get to $v/2\pi^2 * 2m/\hbar^2 \sqrt{\epsilon}* \sqrt{m/2\epsilon\hbar^2} $. Which is the result without a factor 2 wrong, is there anyone who sees my fault?

Comment: I guess that I lied a little. When the density of states is defined for electrons, it generally includes an extra factor of 2 because 2 electrons can go into each state. (I.e. the states a two-fold degenerate.) See Ashcroft and Mermin equation 8.53 and footnote 23 on the same page. That said, in some contexts, this degeneracy factor is kept separate from the density of states. It's more a question of notation than physics. I'll update my answer below.